# VB.NET .Net 6.0 Videoplayer

Tags: vb.net, media-player, .net-6.0

Can someone tell me how to embedd a simple (video) mediaplayer in VB.NET?
.Net 6.0 (in vs2022) does not seem to support a mediaplayer.

Thanks

Comment: Your post needs additional details. It's not clear if you're using Windows Forms or WPF. The following may be helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For WinForms, create a "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" project (ie: use .NET Framework instead of .NET 6). For "WPF Application" (.NET 6), use [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-mediaelement-play-pause-stop-volume-and-speed?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) - this assumes that you are using Windows. If you need something cross-platform, you might check to see if [.NET MAU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui) supports this.

Answer (score 1):

First u add VLC or media player object, here i post how to add media player in tool and how to play simple video files.

By default, 'Windows Media Player' control is not provided in the Toolbox, we have to add it into the toolbox if required.
Inorder to add 'Windows Media Player' control into toolbox

Right click on 'General' tab (or anyother tab) in toolbox ->select 'Choose Items...' ->select 'COM Components' tab ->select 'Windows Media Player' ->click on 'OK' button.

Once u add media player, control will appear in VS tool bar, and from that u drag to ur form design.

Below the code to play video and audio files.

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Windows.Forms

    Namespace mymediaplayer Public Partial Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "(mp3,wav,mp4,mov,wmv,mpg)|*.mp3;*.wav;*.mp4;*.mov;*.wmv;*.mpg|all files|*.*"
        If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName
    End Sub
End Class
   End Namespace
```

Thanks and Regards
Aravind

Comment: I guess I need a different approach then. I use Windows Forms. Hte above does not work,

Comment: above one will work with windows forms Ss - https://prnt.sc/zisBOCpfRSpi,
u need to add mediaplayer control in VS toolbar first using COM object.

Comment: @AravindAravind this is .Net Framework right? He specifically asked for .Net 6.0...